# Linq Query taking too long to load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq, asp.net-core

I have the following linq query -

```
IQueryable<VaccinationClinic> clinics = _appDbContext.VaccinationClinics
                .Include(h => h.HealthBoard)
                .Include(c => c.ClinicType)
                .Include(v => v.VaccinationAvailableTo)
                .Include(p => p.AdministrativeLead).ThenInclude(pn => pn.Title)
                .Include(d => d.ResponsibleSupervisingClinician).ThenInclude(dr => dr.Title)
                .Include(d => d.ResponsibleSupervisingClinician).ThenInclude(dr => dr.ProfessionalBodyDetails)
                .Include(r => r.Designations)
                .Include(t => t.Training)
                .Include(a => a.AnnualFigures).AsQueryable();
```

We do searches on the result e.g. -

```
if (searchCriteria == SearchCriteria.Designated)
{
   clinics = clinics.Where(CheckDesignationIsActive(designationNumberOfDays));
   clinics = clinics.Where(CheckDesignationIsActivePart2(designationNumberOfDays));
   clinics = clinics.Where(sp => !sp.DedesignationDate.HasValue);
}
```

with -

```
private Expression<Func<VaccinationClinic, bool>> CheckDesignationIsActive(int desNumOfDays)
{
   return sp => sp.Designations.OrderByDescending(r => r.DesignatedAt).FirstOrDefault().DesignatedAt.AddYears(sp.Designations.OrderByDescending(r => r.DesignatedAt).FirstOrDefault().NumberOfYears) >= DateTime.Now;
}

private Expression<Func<VaccinationClinic, bool>> CheckDesignationIsActivePart2(int desNumOfDays)
{
   return sp => !((sp.Designations.OrderByDescending(r => r.DesignatedAt).FirstOrDefault().DesignatedAt.AddYears(sp.Designations.OrderByDescending(r => r.DesignatedAt).FirstOrDefault().NumberOfYears) > DateTime.Now) &&
                            (sp.Designations.OrderByDescending(r => r.DesignatedAt).FirstOrDefault().DesignatedAt.AddYears(sp.Designations.OrderByDescending(r => r.DesignatedAt).FirstOrDefault().NumberOfYears) <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(desNumOfDays)));
}
```

And then at the end -

```
 var clinicList = await clinics.AsSplitQuery().ToListAsync();
 return clinicList;
```

The main linq query is taking it's time to load before we add the search criteria, is there anyway to speed it up?

Comment: Is that using Entity Framework (Core?) ? If so, which version?

Comment: Yes.  Entity Framework Core SQL Server 5.0.17 and Entity Framework Core tools 5.0.12

Comment: The speed will depend on the type of database, the machine the database is running on (memory, speed, cores), the type of disk the database is stored on, and the driver than is used to connect c# to the database.  I would start by looking at the connection string to see which driver is used.  When you have a large database it is always best to put on the fastest machine you can find, with the most amount of memory and with the most number of cores.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control on where the database is.  I have updated the entity frame work core SQL Server and Tools to 6.0.12

Comment: Having that many joins and sub joins to load all your data is most likely the cause.  The SQL EF is generating for this query must be insane...

Comment: Check the generated queries and query plans. We can't tell why they take long. We don't even know what "long" is.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to avoid using FirstOrDefault every time when you need value from collection navigation property. It can be done by simple join. I have removed your helper functions usage - it cannot be translated in new query without third party libraries.

```cs
if (searchCriteria == SearchCriteria.Designated)
{
   var clinicsWithDesignation = 
      from c in clinics
      from d in c.Designations
         .OrderByDescending(r => r.DesignatedAt)
         .Take(1)
      select new 
      {
         Clinic = c,
         Designation = d
      };

   clinicsWithDesignation = clinicsWithDesignation
      .Where(cd => cd.Designation.DesignatedAt.AddYears(cd.Designation.NumberOfYears) >= DateTime.Now);

   clinicsWithDesignation = clinicsWithDesignation
      .Where(cd => !((cd.Designation.DesignatedAt.AddYears(cd.Designation.NumberOfYears) > DateTime.Now) &&
                            (cd.Designation.DesignatedAt.AddYears(cd.Designation.NumberOfYears) <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(designationNumberOfDays))));

   clinics = clinicsWithDesignation.Select(cd => cd.Clinic);
   clinics = clinics.Where(sp => !sp.DedesignationDate.HasValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you - try to check it in SQL profiler, how is your query with so many includes translated. I remember in our case in the past (but it was Entity Framework 6) we saw in SQL profiler that our *.Include(...)* were somehow translated to *Union* operation in SQL. After that we decided to rework queries with joins directly through Entity Framework. And we started to have a rule to use *.Include(...)* max 2-times in one query.

Also try to read this article in github:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25731
They are solving the issue with the performance with too many includes and are also explaining why it is like that.

Comment: EF6 and EF Core are two different libraries with different SQL generation, also AsSolitQuery cardinally improves how EF Core processes a lot of Includes.